# Integrating Magento Module for Extra Checkout Fee

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm newer to Magento development and am having quite a difficult time integrating the module explained and laid out here:
http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-development-add-total-row-checkout/

I know that there are some inconsistencies on the walkthrough, which I believe I have accounted for, but still cannot get it in working order.  What I have done so far:

-Created all of the files they outline and the config file:

> /magento/app/code/local/Turnkeye/Insurance/RW/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Totals.php
>   /magento/app/code/local/Turnkeye/Insurance/RW/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Creditmemo/Totals.php
>   /magento/app/code/local/Turnkeye/Insurance/RW/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Invoice/Totals.php
>   /magento/app/code/local/Turnkeye/Insurance/etc/config.xml
>   /magento/app/code/local/Turnkeye/Insurance/Model/Total/Insurance/Quote.php
>   /magento/app/code/local/Turnkeye/Insurance/Model/Total/Insurance/Creditmemo.php
>   /magento/app/code/local/Turnkeye/Insurance/Model/Total/Screen/Invoice.php

-Created a helper file:
    class Turnkeye_Insurance_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
    { }

After doing all of this, I'm getting an error when trying to add a product to the cart: address total model should be extended from Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract .  Unfortunately that is where I've reached the limit of what I know.  Any help with any errors I may have done or any idea what that error may be coming from, that would be awesome!